# Using the linear regression equation in the Bayesian Model Averaging with R

Tags: statistics, bayesian, linear-regression

I am trying to find the best model from linear regression equations where independent variables are principal component scores and the dependent variable is survival time.

These scores correspond to different biological data types like mRNA and miRNa for a particular cancer. The equation also accounts for interactions between these data types by multiplying the score vectors with each other.

Due to multiple equation generations, I need to find the best one using Bayesian Model Averaging in R. But I don't know how to input the equation's independent variables in the function bicreg() of BMA package.

Below is the equation where X is the data type principal components score and beta is the intercept and other are coefficients:

[Regression Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQlo5.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this question would fare better at stats (dot) stackexchange (dot) com.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will post there.